# How to round up the time to next hour in QT?

Tags: qt

This is the code:

```
startDate->setDateTime( QDateTime::currentDateTime() );
finishDate->setDateTime( QDateTime::currentDateTime() );
finishDate->setDateTime(startDate->dateTime().addSecs( 3600 ));
```

For example the time now is 13:34

I need the start time to be rounded up to 14:00
Also the finish time to rounded up to 15:00

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Can please provide an example also? thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you will always operate on recent dates (never older than 1970) you can use so called unixtime and simple math, like this:

```
uint unixtime  = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t(); // current unix time
uint roundHour = unixtime + (3600 - unixtime % 3600); // round it up to an hour
QDateTime start;
QDateTime hourLater;
start.setTime_t(roundHour); // set start datetime to rounded time
hourLater.setTime_t(roundHour + 3600); // set finish time to one hour later
startDate->setDateTime(start);
finishDate->setDateTime(hourLater);
```

Comment: I've tried your code I get this error: test.cpp: ‘class QDateTimeEdit’ has no member named ‘setTime_t’
test.cpp:62: error: ‘class QDateTimeEdit’ has no member named ‘setTime_t’
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
$

Comment: Oh, so `startDate` and `finishDate` are `QDateTimeEdit`. I assumed they were just `QDateTime`. Let me update the example.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right. Did not notice this, so I deleted my answer. Thank you for pointing me and +1 for you.

Comment: I would prefer  `roundHour = (unixtime  +  (3600-1)) % 3600;` in terms of clearness and the number of needed operations, but these are details.